# Percentage in Php

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a mark up percentage to the $cents per Mile, for some reason it ignores it.
How can I create a var that I can enter a whole number for percentage and have it add it to the cost?

```
<?php 
$PriceofgallonGas = 2.59 ;
$precent = 50 ; 
?>



<?php
    function installVanFuel() {

        global $PriceofgallonGas,$precent;
        $TankMiles = 254;   
        $SizeofTankinGallons = 31;
        $mpg = $TankMiles / $SizeofTankinGallons;

        $markup = (1 + $percent/100);
        $centsPerMile = $PriceofgallonGas/$mpg;  
        echo round($centsPerMile*$markup, 2); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: attach your desire output.

Comment: At `$markup = (1 + $percent/100);` you miss spelled the variable `$percent`.

Comment: Fuel Cost = .32 cents x 50%

Comment: what does `echo round($centsPerMile*$markup, 2); ` return??

Comment:  It was my spelling that was causing the issues.... Thank you, Time go for a walk... lol

Comment: Frayne Konok, I'm learning php.... I'm trying for get the math to add a mark up percentage to the cost of fuel per mile. Is that what your asking? I haven't gotten into return values, yet...

Comment: I have design your output as you told. Your calculation is ok, but if you need to show the `%` sign in output then you need to design it.

Comment: How would I add the % to the output if needed? as a string? '%';

Comment: did you check my answer completely? I add a percent sign. Just concatenate the sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake, please check.

At `$markup = (1 + $percent/100);` you miss spelled the variable `$percent`.

```
$PriceofgallonGas = 2.59 ;
$precent = 50 ; 

function installVanFuel() { 
    global $PriceofgallonGas, $precent;
    $TankMiles = 254;   
    $SizeofTankinGallons = 31;
    $mpg = $TankMiles / $SizeofTankinGallons;

    $markup = (1 + $precent/100);
    $centsPerMile = $PriceofgallonGas/$mpg;  
    echo round($centsPerMile*$markup, 2)." Cents x ".$precent."%"; //0.47 Cents x 50%
}
installVanFuel();
```